# How to avoid HTML escaping in noscript tag when including content using SSI

Tags: html, noscript, html-escape

I have a jsp page with

```
<noscript>
    <!--#include virtual="path" -->
</noscript>
```

The include contains
    Text
Result which I expect is the "Text" displayed in the browser. Instead of that I get "Text" displayed in the browser. Can I somehow render that HTML correctly?

UPDATE:
When I enter on the page first time, raw HTML is displayed, but when I enter on the page second time, HTML is rendered correctly, and I get only "Text" text.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is not that of a noscript element.

Comment: what do you mean? Noscript content is displayed when JS is disabled, so it fits perfect as my solution, but it escapes html, and I cannot include content from other server.

Comment: It doesn't escape HTML.

Comment: Screenshot showing that noscript doesn't escape HTML: http://note.io/1ojVJjD

Comment: Umm yes - I asked the question not as I should. Sorry. Of course if I will just put the html in noscript tag - it will be displayed properly, however if the content is server by SSI, it is displayed as raw text.

Comment: Normal use of SSI won't escape content either.

Comment: In normal use yes, but I have a jsp page, which have the 
                <noscript>
                        <!--#include virtual="somePath" -->
                </noscript>
And in the result I got the <div class="abc">Text</div>

Comment: My reading of the JSP manual suggests that includes are handled above the level of JSP and that virtual does a straight include of the content. So that shouldn't cause it to be escaped either. I'm not running a JSP capable server so I can't test it though.

Comment: Sadly I've got the problem on my machine, and I don't know why. I also think that it should be displayed correctly, but it doesn't. And What I just saw:
Raw HTML is displyed only when I enter on the page first time. When I enter on that page second time, HTML displays correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was caused by bug in chrome. More details here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232410